# Find duplicates by id and restructure the dataset in R

Tags: r, group-by

I have a dataset with columns: `id`, `names`. There can be one `id` but multiple `names`, so I am getting duplicate `id-rows` at times:

```
id   names

id1 name1 
id1 name2 
id1 name3
id2 name4
id2 name5
```

I need to restructure such a `data.frame` in `R`, so that all rows would have unique `ids`, and if there are multiple `names`, they all should be written into the `names` column as comma separated values like that:

```
id   names
id1  name1, name2, name3
id2  name4, name5
```

I tried `grouped <- table %>% group_by(names)` but it did not work.

How could I achieve that in R?

Comment: While the answers in the duplicate question work, none of them are optimal IMO.  Try `grouped <- table %>% group_by(names) %>% summarize(names=list(names))`

Comment: I got an error that `names` is a grouping variable and can not be modified.

Comment: Sorry, group by `id` not names.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `data.table`:

```
 df <- read.table(header=T, text="id   names

                             id1 name1 
                             id1 name2 
                             id1 name3
                             id2 name4
                             id2 name5")

    library(data.table)
    setDT(df)
    df[, names := as.character(names)]
    df[, names := paste0(names, collapse = ", "), by = id]
    df <- unique(df)
```

Output:

```
df
    id               names
1: id1 name1, name2, name3
2: id2        name4, name5
```